# Why is this ajax call to the correct php script not returning anything?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this AJAX:

```
function sendMail () {
        $.post('php/sendMail.php', function(result){
            alert(result);
        })
    }

$('#submitContact').click(function(){
        sendMail();
    })
```

and this PHP:

```
<?php

$trimmed = array_map('trim', $_POST);

$message = $trimmed['message'];
$email = $trimmed['email'];
$name = $trimmed['name'];

if (empty($message)) {
    $message = FALSE;
}

if (empty($email)) {
    $message = FALSE;
}

if (empty($name)) {
    $message = FALSE;
}

if ($message && $email && $name){

    $body = "From: $name.\n \n $message";

    mail(/*some email*/, 'Website Contact Form Submission', $body, "From: $email");

    echo ('success');

}

echo($message.' '.$email.' '.$name);

?>
```

All the html elements defined exist. When I run it all that returns is a blank alert box (meaning that the PHP script did not print out success). Any idea why it is not sending the mail?

Comment: Use firebug (if you use FF), developer tools if you use chrome or another appropriate tool to debug your http requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't appear to be sending any data with your `POST`.

If you're trying to submit a form, try this:

```
$.post('php/sendMail.php',$('form').serialize(), function(result){
        alert(result);
    })
```

Edit: As Tomalak rightly points out in the comments, you'll need to specify which form you are serializing. I'd normally give the form an `id` and use that:- `$('#myform').serialize()`

Comment: Which form are you serialising?

Comment: @Tomalak I don't know, the HTML isn't available. It's just meant as an example - I'd use an ID in place of 'form'.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that in the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending any data to that URL.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing an empty alert box is because `$email` and `$name` is empty because you didn't pass any `$_POST` variable.
And `$message = FALSE` is blank when you echo it.
Try changing this line

```
echo($message.' '.$email.' '.$name);
```

To

```
var_dump($message.' '.$email.' '.$name);
```

And you'll see the value of `$message.' '.$email.' '.$name`.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea why it is not sending the mail?

Put simply, *you didn't ask it to*.

---

The syntax for `$.post` is:

> jQuery.post( url, [data,] [success(data, textStatus, jqXHR),] [dataType] )

The way jQuery works, you *may* skip the `data` argument and still provide the following ones, but in this case you're simply not passing any data for your PHP script to work with.

Assuming that `#submitContact` is a button in the form that you want to submit, you should serialise that form's contents and send that as the `POST` data:

```
function sendMail($form) {
    $.post('php/sendMail.php', $form.serialize(), function(result) {
        alert(result);
    });
}

var $btn = $('#submitContact');
var $frm = $btn.parents('form');
$btn.click(function() {
    sendMail($frm);
});
```

[The documentation is your friend. **Use it.**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

---

<sup>(**Note:** The `$` at the start of some of my variables is deliberate; it's a personal choice that jQuery objects have names starting with `$` in my code.)</sup>